# Missing Build Dependencies when upload to Launchpad

Tags: launchpad, dependencies, build

bit of a different question.

I'm trying to upload a package to a repository that I just started on Launchpad. Launchpad accepts the upload happily, and everything seems good up until the build. It cuts itself short part-way through, reporting "Missing build dependencies: libswfdec-0.8-dev".

Now, this package is listed in the Control file. So I'm not sure what's going on here, but I feel like it's a very novice mistake, since this is my first (attempted) upload.

The main page shows the following text:

```
Build status

Dependency wait on king (virtual) Retry this build
Missing build dependencies: libswfdec-0.8-dev
Started 5 minutes ago
Finished 2 minutes ago (took 3 minutes, 30.4 seconds)
buildlog (4.3 KiB)
```

and the buildlog shows (amongst other things):

```
libswfdec-0.8-dev: missing
libswfdec-0.8-dev: does not exist
```

This of course, compiles fine on my system. If anybody has a suggestion, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this for Natty? If so ... there does not seem to be a libswfdec for Natty(??)

Comment: no the build is for Maverick. I haven't installed Natty on any of my systems yet, but hopefully I'll be building this for 11.04 once I get the Maverick build up.

Comment: Frustrating :=) Did you see this on debian bugs: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=573673 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libswfdec was removed from Ubuntu & Debian so you will not be able to build that file in your Maverick PPA.

See the Ubuntu [source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swfdec0.8) and the Debian [removal bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=571666).

Since this file is still in Lucid you may be able to build it there. See [this page](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading) for more info about how to push to a different release.

Comment: That's bizarre. Was this a recent change? I'm building a modified version of Gloobus-Preview, and the Gloobus team obviously has been successful with building on Maverick even though it relies on that package. Do you know of a way to fix this or do I just have to remove the code that relies on libswfdec to build past Lucid?